# Highcharts 3.0 & Quirks Mode & IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, highcharts

We are trying to integrate Highcharts into our BI portal. The portal is out of the box product certified for IE 8 and earlier. Designed a page that renders the graph using HighCharts. This page is called within an iFrame on the portal. The graph page reneders fine when it is called by itself, however when it is called within the iFrame, the graph has some issues. Unfortunately we cannot control how the portal is designed. Any ideas or suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle (it's also within iframe).

Comment: Its hard to reproduce the issue in jsFiddle. Is there a way I can upload the HTML file?

Comment: I contacted support and they opened a case in github: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1815

Comment: They also can't reproduce that issue..